# Pushing tags with Jenkins Git Publisher - multiple Git repositories (forks)

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

Our team is transitioning from CVS to Git.  We intend to use the similar workflow as most open source projects on GitHub - each developer takes a fork of the main repo and then submits a pull request which will allow the project master to do a code review before merging the changes into the main repo.

Jenkins allows us to add multiple Git repositories (the standard Git plugin, not the Multiple SCM one).  Presumably I can enter the URL for each forked repo and then Jenkins will check all branches each fork for changes.  I give each repository a name eg "master", "developer1", "developer2"...

We want to have Jenkins tagging each build on the appropriate remote/fork.  The Git Publisher plugin requires that you provide the "target remote name", but we need Jenkins to be able to figure this out for itself.

Answer (score 16):

I've managed to solve this one myself.

- At the top of the Jenkins project config page check "This build is parameterized" and add a string parameter "remote" with default "master".
- Add "Git Publisher" as a Post-build action, and a Tag "$BUILD_TAG" and Target remote name = "$remote"
- In Build Triggers, check "Trigger builds remotely"
- We're using GitLab and under the project Settings menu I add a "Web Hook":

  http://my-jenkins-server.com/job/my-project/buildWithParameters?token=secret&remote=master

Add a web hook for each fork, and make sure that the "remote" parameter matches the repository name configured in Jenkins.